# I get a count() error when I use the greater than, less than or equal to filter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

On the books page, I added a filter by the number of authors of books, where I can specify (=n | >n | <n).

```
public function findPaginated(InterpretationTranslationSourceFilter $filter): NewPaginator
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->leftJoin('s.authorToSourceRelations', 'atsr')
        ->select('s as interpretationTranslationSource')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT atsr.id) AS authorToSourceRelationsCount')
        ->groupBy('s.id');

    if ($filter->isHasLink() OR $filter->getDontHasLink()) {
        if ($filter->isHasLink()) {
            $qb->andWhere('s.url IS NOT NULL');
        }

        if ($filter->getDontHasLink()) {
            $qb->andWhere('s.url IS NULL');
        }
    }

    if ($filter->getSortByAuthorsCount()) {
        $comparisonOperator = substr($filter->getSortByAuthorsCount(), 0, 1);
        $authorsCount = (int) substr($filter->getSortByAuthorsCount(), 1);

        switch ($comparisonOperator) {
            case '=':
                $qb->having('authorToSourceRelationsCount = :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            case '>':
                $qb->having('authorToSourceRelationsCount > :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            case '<':
                $qb->having('authorToSourceRelationsCount < :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            default:
                $qb->orderBy('s.title', 'ASC');
                break;
        }
    }

    if ($filter->getTitle()) {
        $qb->andWhere('s.title like :title')
            ->setParameter('title', '%' . $filter->getTitle() . '%');
    }

    if ($filter->getUrl()) {
        $qb->andWhere('s.url LIKE :url')
            ->setParameter('url', '%' . $filter->getUrl() . '%');
    }

    return new NewPaginator($qb, $filter);
}
```

When I specify any value I get the error:
*count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Andx given*

I tried to supplement my queries, rebuild them, but all in vain

Answer (score 0):

Change the `HAVING` clause by `COUNT(DISTINCT atsr.id)` directly in the condition. This should resolve the issue. The HAVING clause should operate on the result of the aggregate function, and in this case, it's the count of distinct author IDs.

```
switch ($comparisonOperator) {
            case '=':
                $qb->having('COUNT(DISTINCT atsr.id) = :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            case '>':
                $qb->having('COUNT(DISTINCT atsr.id) > :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            case '<':
                $qb->having('COUNT(DISTINCT atsr.id) < :authorsCount')
                    ->setParameter('authorsCount', $authorsCount);
                break;
            default:
                $qb->orderBy('s.title', 'ASC');
                break;
}
```

*Try to replace `having` by `andHaving` if you still have a problem*